# How do I initialize a custom array type from the main file in Ada

Tags: computer-science, ada, spark-ada

I am an Ada noob, and am writing a simple function that takes a list of integers and decrements each element by 1. My bronze mode proof passes ok but trying to actually use the function in the main to see if it is actually doing what it is supposed to is proving a struggle. I'm not sure how I initialize the array and assign values (which are supposed to be 0..10). I'm also not sure if I could have implemented this with just the one decrement function as opposed to  decrement(integer) and a decrementList(ArrayOfNumbers) functions. Or if I'm doing it right at all. Any help would be ace, there is not any good documentation that I have found so I feel like I'm supposed to guess my way round. The package is called flip_coin as it is part of an earlier task, anything related to flipping coins can be ignored!

here is the spec file:

```
package flip_coin with SPARK_Mode is

    type Coin is (Heads, Tails);

    type Index is range 0 .. 10;
  
    type Numbers is array (Index) of Integer;

    function flip (x : Coin) return Coin with
 
     Post => flip'Result /= x;

    procedure flipCoin (x : in out Coin);

    function decrement (i : Integer) return Integer;
    
    procedure decrementList (n : in out Numbers);

 end flip_coin;
```

Here is the body file:

```
package body flip_coin with SPARK_Mode is

    function flip (x : Coin) return Coin
    is
      begin
        if x = Heads then return Tails; else return Heads; end if;
    end flip;

    procedure flipCoin (x : in out Coin)
    is
    begin
      x := flip(x);
   end flipCoin;

   function decrement (i : Integer) return Integer
   is
   begin
      return i-1;
   end decrement;

   procedure decrementList (n : in out Numbers) is

      a : Index := n'First;
      b : Index := n'Last;
   begin
      for i in a..b loop
         n(i) := decrement(n(i));
      end loop;
   end decrementList;



end flip_coin;
```

and here is the main file:

```
with flip_coin; use flip_coin;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   newCoin : Coin := Heads;
   numbers : Numbers := (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
 begin
   Put_Line("Element 9, before decrement:");
   Put_Line(numbers(9)'Image);
   decrementList(numbers);
   Put_Line("Element 9, after decrement:");
   Put_Line(numbers(9)'Image);
   Put_Line("Coin before flip:");
   Put_Line(newCoin'Image);
   flipCoin(newCoin);
   Put_Line("Coin after flip:");
   Put_Line(newCoin'Image);
end Main;
```

here is my error when I try to run:

```
main.adb:6:14: object "Numbers" cannot be used before end of its declaration
```

Any help again greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ada is case insensitive language. Thus, numbers and Numbers are the same. How about change numbers to numbers_array.

Answer (score 4):

This is a visibility issue, and why beginners should avoid `use <package>`. Understanding visibility is key to understanding Ada. Avoiding use-package clauses makes you think about visibility and helps you understand it.

You have 2 things named `Numbers`, with full names of `Flip_Coin.Numbers` and `Main.Numbers`. Within `Main`, the local name `Numbers` hides the use-visible `Numbers` from `Flip_Coin`. It can still be referenced as `Flip_Coin.Numbers`.

The best introduction to visibility in Ada is [*Ada Distilled*](https://www.adaic.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Ada-Distilled-24-January-2011-Ada-2005-Version.pdf).